# Как ограничить Firefox потребление оперативной памяти без убийства процесса?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, ram

Очень долго не могу найти решение проблемы контроля использования оперативной памяти Firefox (да и другими программами) так, чтобы это работало, как действует утилита Firemin в Windows, т.е. чтобы не происходило удаления процесса при превышении определенного порога использования RAM в системе.

Можно ли получить от специалистов четкую инструкцию, как настроить такое поведение для любой программы в Ubuntu?

Есть разные утилиты (Earlyoom, Nohang и прочее), есть cgroup, но там как я понимаю, все в итоге приводит к убийству процесса и это грубое решение, приводящее к не комфортному использованию того же Firefox.

Нужно именно настроить ограничение так, чтобы например при достижении браузером уровня 700Мб RAM, дальше эта цифра не возрастала и браузер при этом корректно продолжал свою работу.

Comment: Как вы себе это представляете? Программе нужна память, она ее не получает, но приэтом должна продолжить корректно работать?

Comment: я тоже хочу такую программу:) это же можно сколько софта запустить на моей машине будет!

Comment: @user207200 так же как и Firemin, наверное?

Comment: @andreymal "это другое"

Comment: Коллега подсказывает `MemoryMax=bytes` из https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html

Comment: @user207200 - скидывать в дисковый кеш что не поместилось в оперативке. одного гига достаточно для серфинга, но браузер может скушать 16 если ему их дать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый момент - если процесс кушает память, то он считает её свободной, а если она свободна то почему бы не позволить ему её кушать? Пусть ест!

В случае cgroup нужно выделить память в подкачке, тогда процесс не будет убит по OOM

```
cgcreate -g memory:firefoxlimited
echo 700M > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/firefoxlimited/memory.limit_in_bytes
echo 4G > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/firefoxlimited/memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes

cgexec -g memory:firefoxlimited firefox
```

или убрать килера

```
echo 1 > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/firefoxlimited/memory.oom_control
```

Не забудьте включить cgroup в загрузчике `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=".... cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 ...."
```

и
`sudo update-grub`

В cgroup2 параметры называются подругому и создать группу проще

https://facebookmicrosites.github.io/cgroup2/docs/create-cgroups.html

https://facebookmicrosites.github.io/cgroup2/docs/memory-controller.html

Comment: Большое спасибо предельно ясный ответ. Единственное уточнение теперь только насчет размера подкачки. Например у меня ноутбук с Убунту, ОЗУ 6 Гб и разделом swap также на 6 Гб. Если допустим я хочу через cgroup выделять Firefox не более 700-900 Мб ОЗУ, то сколько тогда оптимально выделить памяти в подкачке? Есть ли какие-то соотношения и как можно их определять вообще для любых иных программ/процессов?